# sql join on multiple list of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a an sql Postgres table with a composite ID and I want to fill wide range of value on this table, if the data aren't already exist.
I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
idCol1              VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
idCol2              VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
idCol3              VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
amount              VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
)
```

And for all the value of idCol1 in ['A','B','C'], idCol2 in ['D','E','F'], idCol3 in ['G','H','I'] I want to set an amount value, if the row don't already exist.

The issue is the idCol1, idCol2 and idCol3 aren't foreing key and their value is not in any table. I have to fill those directly into the sql query.

I have trouble to write a request who simultaneously insert data, do a join on 3 differentes array of data and don't erase existing data.

How can I do-it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `varchar(256)` offers no performance or storage advantages over e.g. `varchar(321)` or `varchar(258)`

Comment: Do you really store a comma separated string like `['A','B','C']` (including the square brackets) in those columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to insert rows that are not present?  If so:

```
insert into mytable (idcol1, idcol2, idcol3, amount)
    select i1.idcol1, i2.idcol2, i3.idcol3, 0 as amount
    from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')) i1(idcol1) CROSS JOIN
         (values ('D'), ('E'), ('F')) i2(idcol2) CROSS JOIN
         (values ('G'), ('H'), ('I')) i3(idcol3) LEFT JOIN
         mytable t
         USING (idcol1, idcol2, idcol3)
    where t.idcol1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: For information my issue was I did'nt use CROSS JOIN, only ',' to do the cartesian product. Your solution work, thank-you !

Comment: @sab . . . `,` IS `CROSS JOIN`.  I strongly recommend that you use `CROSS JOIN` because it more clearly shows the intention of the code.